# Jade content following self closing tag

Tags: html, pug

I am converting some HTML from a preexisting application into Jade.  I have a block of HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="data[day][sunday]" value="sunday">
  Sunday
  </label>
</div>
```

What would the equivalent Jade be for this?  Ideally it would look something like this:

```
div(class="checkbox"):
  label 
    input(type="checkbox" name="data[day][sunday]" value="sunday") 
    Sunday
```

But because `input` is a self closing tag, I can't follow it with the text "Sunday"

I have no problem writing this in another way that works exactly as I need, but I want to know how to solve this problem exactly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `|` in jade to solve this problem.

Any text that follows a `|` will be interpreted as text in the parent

```
div(class="checkbox"):
  label 
    input(type="checkbox" name="data[day][sunday]" value="sunday") 
    | Sunday
```

You can also use non-self closing tags like this

```
div
  div
    span hello there
  | and plain text
```

will result in html like this

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>hello there</span>
  </div>
  and plain text
</div>
```

Keeping in mind that writing straight HTML inside Jade is completely valid, you can solve this problem like this as well.

```
div(class="checkbox"):
  label.
    <input type="checkbox" name="#{data[day][sunday]}" value="sunday"> 
    Sunday
```

The `.` following a tag in Jade will treat all content like text.

Comment: Thanks your answer worked well!  I'm not at my computer now to test this out, but I assume I can use this same principle if I want to take advantage of Jade's block expansion?  How would that look?  My guess is this:

`div(class="checkbox"): label: input(type="checkbox" name="data[day][sunday]" value=") | Sunday`

Comment: @MichaelHamilton Yes, the `|` works no matter which type of tag you use. I've edited my answer to reflect this